# How to avoid images from wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

I have inserted an image in wordpress theme header.And now the image shows in all wordpress pages.I want to avoid that please help me.

Comment: Generally, the header will be used on all pages, so this is normal behaviour. I believe what you're after would require editing your theme. Is it a purchased theme, maybe you can ask the creators for customising options?

Comment: I am sorry.It's not in the header section it's in the image slider section.

Comment: I just added an image in theme.But it shows in all pages .Please help me to avoid this.

Comment: Try adding the image in the 'Featured Image' section, when editing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that case you can use the conditional tag, For example, if you want to display the image in only contact page, then u can use this code:      if(is_page( 'Contact' )) {                                                     Put your image code here                                    }                                                                                where Contact is the title of that page
Hope it helps.